Returning a reference of an enum variant in Rust
In the following code which I modified from The Rust Programming Language book chapter 13
#[derive(Debug)]
enum ShirtColor {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Yello,
}

struct Inventory {
    shirts: Vec<ShirtColor>,
}

impl<'a> Inventory {
    fn giveaway(&self, user_pref: Option<&'a ShirtColor>) -> &'a ShirtColor {
        user_pref.unwrap_or_else(|| self.most_stocked())
    }

    fn most_stocked(&self) -> &'a ShirtColor {
        let mut red_count = 0;
        let mut blue_count = 0;
        let mut yello_count = 0;

        for color in &self.shirts {
            match color {
                ShirtColor::Red => red_count += 1,
                ShirtColor::Blue => blue_count += 1,
                ShirtColor::Yello => yello_count += 1,
            }
        }

        if red_count > blue_count && red_count > yello_count {
            &ShirtColor::Red
        } else if blue_count > red_count && blue_count > yello_count {
            &ShirtColor::Blue
        } else {
            &ShirtColor::Yello
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let store = Inventory {
        shirts: vec![
            ShirtColor::Blue,
            ShirtColor::Red,
            ShirtColor::Blue,
            ShirtColor::Yello,
            ShirtColor::Yello,
            ShirtColor::Yello,
        ],
    };

    let user_pref1 = Some(&ShirtColor::Red);
    let giveaway1 = store.giveaway(user_pref1);
    println!(
        "The user with preference {:?} gets {:?}",
        user_pref1, giveaway1
    );

    let user_pref2 = None;
    let giveaway2 = store.giveaway(user_pref2);
    println!(
        "The user with preference {:?} gets {:?}",
        user_pref2, giveaway2
    );
}


I wonder why I can return a reference to ShirtColor variants inside the most_stocked method
What I think is that these values will died when we go out of the method so there will be a dangling reference here
I know I am wrong so can any one explain why this code is valid ?

This is a bit of magic intended for convenience called constant promotion

@drewtato Thank you very much, it is more clear now

So to simplify the example, imagine that we replace the most_stocked method with a just_red method that just returns red no matter what:
fn just_red(&self) -> &'a ShirtColor {
        &ShirtColor::Red
}

The reason why this works is that it is not equivalent to this:
fn just_red(&self) -> &'a ShirtColor {
        let red = ShirtColor::Red;
        &red
}

Which as you expected does not compile due to the dangling reference issue.
And so basically what's going on here is that rust knows that ShirtColor::Red is a constant value, and so if you go to borrow it using &, this borrow has the 'static lifetime.  So the type of &ShirtColor::Red is &'static ShirtColor.  Since the function is supposed to return a &'a ShirtColor, and 'static is longer than 'a ('static is longer than all other lifetimes), the &'static ShirtColor coerces into a &'a ShirtColor to be returned.  In contrast, if we first bind let red = ShirtColor::Red, the value of &red has an anonymous lifetime which ends at the end of the current function when the local variable red is dropped.  Therefore, the lifetime of &red is shorter than 'a and so &red cannot be coerced into &'a ShirtColor, and so it does not match the return type of the function, and cannot be returned.
